# Media query for same width different heights

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

Best way to apply media query for same width and different heights ?

For example i have this sample code

```
    @media screen and (max-width: 1366px), screen and (max-height: 657px){
        article#chapterthankyou{
        width:984px;
        }

    }
```

and

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1366px), screen and (max-height: 768px){

         article#chapterthankyou{
        width:1048px;
        }

    }
```

The problem is, even on `1366 X 657` the `article#chapterthankyou{
        width:984px;
        }` style is applied.

How can i accurately apply height width conditions ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, but according to [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) on the MDN, you are a little off with your logical operators.

For your code, try using this:

```
@media screen 
and (max-width: 1366px)
and (max-height: 657px){

        article#chapterthankyou{
        width:984px;

        }
    }
```

And...

```
@media screen 
and (max-width: 1366px)
and (max-height: 768px){

        article#chapterthankyou{
        width:1048px;

        }
    }
```

If this still does not work, then refer [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) for a list of different media queries, which you might find useful.